# Java Realm Saving Data from JSON - No Time Zone Indicator

Tags: java, json, realm

i am trying to synchronize some data with my mobile app which uses `realm` as its local DB and we have a `MS SQL` db on cloud. I am trying to pull data from the web service and when i'm trying to save the returned JSON.

It says:

`java.text.ParseException: Failed to parse date ["2020-04-03T13:51:02"]: No time zone indicator (at offset 0)`

I do understand what it is trying to say but i want to remove the dependency on time zone since our dates on MS SQL already has offsets but it is not return the timezone though.

Comment: Were you able to fix the issue?